Pandas - Convert Multiple colums to rows in Dataframe
I have df as below:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {
    'NIFTYBEES.NS': [0.26, 0.18],
    'abc.NS': [0.1, 0.1],
    'NIFTYBEES.NS_pct_change': [0.86, -0.21],
    'abc.NS_pct_change': [0.2, 0.2],
    'avg': [0.4775, 0.76],
    'weekday': ['Monday', 'Tuesday']
}
Date = pd.date_range('2024-04-29', periods=2, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=Date)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Use melt to reshape the DataFrame
df_melted = df.melt(id_vars=['index', 'avg', 'weekday'], value_vars=df.filter(regex='\.NS$').columns, 
                    var_name='etf', value_name='value')
df_melted['etf_mrr'] = df_melted['value']
df_melted.drop(columns=['value'], inplace=True)
df_melted = df_melted[['index', 'etf', 'etf_mrr', 'avg', 'weekday']]
df_melted.rename(columns={'index': 'Date'}, inplace=True)
print(df_melted)

Current Output:
    Date           etf  etf_mrr     avg  weekday
0 2024-04-29  NIFTYBEES.NS     0.26  0.4775   Monday
1 2024-04-30  NIFTYBEES.NS     0.18  0.7600  Tuesday
2 2024-04-29        abc.NS     0.10  0.4775   Monday
3 2024-04-30        abc.NS     0.10  0.7600  Tuesday

For Column Ending with .NS_pct_change, I need one more column as pct_change, in melt condition , I checked with OR Condition its not working, also single melt statement is not able to create multiple columns.
I need expected output as below:
Expected Output:
        Date           etf  etf_mrr etf_pct_change  avg  weekday
0 2024-04-29  NIFTYBEES.NS     0.26     0.86        0.4775   Monday
1 2024-04-29  abc.NS           0.1      0.2        0.4775   Monday
2 2024-04-30  NIFTYBEES.NS     0.18     -0.21       0.7600  Tuesday
3 2024-04-30  abc.NS           0.1      0.2      0.7600  Tuesday


You want to create column etf_pct_change but pls explain the logic of its calculation

Column: *.NS_pct_change column values should be added in etf_pct_change column which contain same prefix abc.NS, NIFTYBEES.NS. Updated Input and Expected Output

Sorry. Still the logic is unclear to me

One Solution I have is to have two different df initially to melt columns which contains \.NS_pct_change$ & \.NS$
Created two df: df1 & df2 from original df:
df1 = df.melt(id_vars=['index', 'avg', 'weekday'], value_vars=df.filter(regex='\.NS$').columns, 
                    var_name='etf', value_name='value')
df1['etf_mrr'] = df1['value']
df1.drop(columns=['value'], inplace=True)
df1 = df1[['index', 'etf', 'etf_mrr', 'avg', 'weekday']]
df1.rename(columns={'index': 'Date'}, inplace=True)
print(df1)

df2 = df.melt(id_vars=['index', 'avg', 'weekday'], value_vars=df.filter(regex='\.NS_pct_change$').columns, 
                    var_name='etf', value_name='value')
df2['etf_pct_change'] = df2['value']
df2.drop(columns=['value'], inplace=True)
df2 = df2[['index', 'etf', 'etf_pct_change', 'avg', 'weekday']]
df2.rename(columns={'index': 'Date'}, inplace=True)
print(df2)

Output of df1 & df2:
df1

  Date           etf  etf_mrr     avg  weekday
0 2024-04-29  NIFTYBEES.NS     0.26  0.4775   Monday
1 2024-04-30  NIFTYBEES.NS     0.18  0.7600  Tuesday
2 2024-04-29        abc.NS     0.10  0.4775   Monday
3 2024-04-30        abc.NS     0.10  0.7600  Tuesday

df2

  Date                      etf  etf_pct_change     avg  weekday
0 2024-04-29  NIFTYBEES.NS_pct_change            0.86  0.4775   Monday
1 2024-04-30  NIFTYBEES.NS_pct_change           -0.21  0.7600  Tuesday
2 2024-04-29        abc.NS_pct_change            0.20  0.4775   Monday
3 2024-04-30        abc.NS_pct_change            0.20  0.7600  Tuesday

Then add column from df2: etf_pct_change to df1:
df1['etf_pct_change'] = df2['etf_pct_change']
df1

Output:

    Date           etf         etf_mrr  avg    weekday  etf_pct_change
0   2024-04-29  NIFTYBEES.NS    0.26    0.4775  Monday  0.86
1   2024-04-30  NIFTYBEES.NS    0.18    0.7600  Tuesday -0.21
2   2024-04-29  abc.NS          0.10    0.4775  Monday  0.20
3   2024-04-30  abc.NS          0.10    0.7600  Tuesday 0.20


Code
use wide_to_long
1.rename columns to use wide_to_long
tmp = (
    df.rename(lambda x: f'etf_mrr_{x}' if x.endswith('.NS') else x, axis=1)
      .rename(lambda x: f'etf_pct_change_{x.replace("_pct_change", "")}' 
              if x.endswith('_pct_change') else x, axis=1)
)

tmp:

2.reshape dataframe using wide_to_long
out = (
    pd.wide_to_long(
        tmp, 
        stubnames=['etf_mrr', 'etf_pct_change'], 
        i=['index', 'avg', 'weekday'], 
        j='etf', 
        sep='_', 
        suffix='.+')
    .reset_index()
    .rename({'index': 'Date'}, axis=1)
)[['Date', 'etf', 'etf_mrr', 'etf_pct_change', 'avg', 'weekday']]

out:


It returned a result with the date column on the leftmost, followed by the ETF-specific columns. If you don't want to hardcode this, use the following code
out = (
    pd.wide_to_long(
        tmp, 
        stubnames=['etf_mrr', 'etf_pct_change'], 
        i=['index', 'avg', 'weekday'], 
        j='etf', 
        sep='_', 
        suffix='.+')
    .reset_index([1, 2, 3])
    .sort_index(
        key=lambda x: x.map(lambda x: x if 'etf' in x else None), axis=1)
    .reset_index()
    .rename({'index': 'Date'}, axis=1)
)

same result
